# Spring Boot Lattice CF

Tags: java, spring, cloud-foundry

When I use the following command using the windows ltc client:

ltc build-droplet lattice-demo java --memory-mb 512 --path=build/libs/lattice-demo-1.0.0.jar

or

ltc build-droplet lattice-demo java --memory-mb=512 --path=build/libs/lattice-demo-1.0.0.jar

followed by:
ltc launch-droplet lattice-demo lattice-demo

The droplet in latticecf only ever allocates 128MB to the container.

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

I am using lattice-bundle-v0.7.0-1-ge5365cd\vagrant>vagrant up --provider virtualbox with 4GB and 6 cpus allocated to the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that [`ltc build-droplet`](http://lattice.cf/docs/ltc/#ltc-build-droplet) doesn't take a `--memory-mb` flag:

> `ltc build-droplet DROPLET_NAME http://github.com/buildpack-url` creates a droplet by running a Cloud Foundry Buildpack on an application directory.
>
> - `--path=.` path to droplet source (file or folder)
> - `--env NAME[=VALUE]` specifies environment variables. You can have multiple `--env` flags. Passing an `--env` flag without explicitly setting the `VALUE` uses the current execution context to set the value.
> - `--timeout=2m` sets the maximum polling duration for building the droplet.

On the other hand, what you really want is to pass that flag to [`ltc launch-droplet`](http://lattice.cf/docs/ltc/#ltc-launch-droplet):

> `ltc launch-droplet` has the same options as `ltc create`, except for `--user`, `--privileged` and `--working-dir`.

And if we look at [`ltc create`](http://lattice.cf/docs/ltc/#ltc-create):

> - `--memory-mb=128` specifies the memory limit to apply to the container.
>
>   - Set this to `0` to allow unlimited memory usage.